# Pad strings to be the same length in a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings that read from file. Each element is a line of file.
I want to have an array of this string that have same length. I want to find the longest string and reformat other strings as long as longest string (with space at the end of them).
Now I find the longest one. but I don't know how can I reformat other strings. Can anybody help me please?

```
with open('cars') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('cars')]
max_in=len(lines[0])
for l in lines:
    print (str(len(l))+" "+str(max_in))
    if max_in < len(l):
        max_in=len(l)
print max_in
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example input and desired output?

Comment: Would you like to pad left or right?

Comment: @ChristianDean I want add space to left.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ of course.

Comment: In the context of Markdown table formatting, from a now-deleted question: https://ideone.com/Damr6L

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with this:

```
In [546]: array = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foobar']
```

Find the length of the largest string using `max`:

```
In [547]: max(array, key=len) # ignore this line (it's for demonstrative purposes)
Out[547]: 'foobar'

In [548]: maxlen = len(max(array, key=len))
```

Now, use a list comprehension and pad left:

```
In [551]: [(' ' * (maxlen - len(x))) + x for x in array]
Out[551]: ['   foo', '   bar', '   baz', 'foobar']
```

Comment: @ChristianDean All you need to do is `string.rjust(len('elephant'))` and it'd work. ;)

Comment: `lines = ['cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'horse']; print([x.rjust(len('elephant')) for x in lines])`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ _sigh_. Man I feel like an idiot. How did I miss the obvious solution right in front me! I keep switching this around, trying different methods, using `abs`. The sad part though, is that I've done exactly what you said before, but for some odd reason I couldn't remember it this time. Anyways, thanks. I guess I'll re-post my answer. Doesn't feel like I deserve the rep now though :P

Comment: @ChristianDean It's a good solution, and more succinct than mine. Trust me you deserve it :) +1'd it

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have your list of strings already read from the file, you can use [`str.rjust()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) to pad your strings left:

```
>>> lines = ['cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'horse']
>>> maxlen = len(max(lines, key=len))
>>> 
>>> [line.rjust(maxlen) for line in lines]
['     cat', '     dog', 'elephant', '   horse']
```

You can also change the character used in the padding:

```
>>> [line.rjust(maxlen, '0') for line in lines]
['00000cat', '00000dog', 'elephant', '000horse']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

1) find max len:

```
max_len = max(len(el) for el in lines)
```

2) add spaces to the ends of others strings:

```
lines = [" "*(max_len - len(el)) + el for el in lines]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your reading the file two times. The first time, the data is never used. You can use `max` to find the maximum, and format, to add the spaces:

```
with open('cars') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
width = max(map(len, lines))
lines = ["{0:>{1}s}".format(line, width) for line in lines]
```

Answer (score 0):

With Thanks from all answers I edit my code as this:

```
with open('cars') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('cars')]
max_line_len = len(max(lines, key=len))
new_lines = [line.ljust(max_line_len) for line in lines]
```