# Modify how specific numbers are displayed using print in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to modify the appearance of numpy arrays, so that specific numbers are displayed in a different way. In my specific case, I would like each number `0` in an array to be displayed as character `e`, and each `-math.inf` to be seen as the Greek character epsilon (`ε` or, in unicode, `\u03B5`).

For instance, when I run the following code

```
A = np.array([[10,1,541],[0,5000,-math.inf]])
print(A)
```

I would like to obtain

```
[[10    1 541]
 [ e 5000   ε]]
```

I've already tried to play around a bit with `numpy.set_printoptions` and the best I could do is:

```
# create a function that returns 'ε' if x is -inf, 'e' if x is 0, 'x' otherwise
my_format_function = lambda x: '\u03B5' if x==-math.inf else ('e' if x==0 else str(x))

# set the function as formatter for numpy's printing options
numpy.set_printoptions(formatter={'all':my_format_function})

# test
A = np.array([[10,1,541],[0,5000,-math.inf]])
print(A)
```

but this scrambles the nice default format offered by numpy (e.g., indentation); I get:

```
[[10.0 1.0 541.0]
 [e 5000.0 ε]]
```

which is not particularly pleasant.

Comment: You also need to use [set_string_function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_string_function.html#numpy.set_string_function) to justify the elements; figure out the max `len` of all of the `str`s in your function, and then pad the rest of them with (pseudocode) `this.rjust(maxlen-len(this))`

Comment: You just stringify here: `'e' if x==0 else str(x)`. Maybe extract the default fromatter from numpy first and then fallback to that.

Comment: Re: pseudocode, you could try something like from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45120703/pad-strings-to-be-the-same-length-in-a-list) (note you'd need to modify to handle `ndarrays` instead of 1D lists)